# Jquery and SQL data table

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Learning Jquery here and I would like to show my SQL table on my webpage. I have the "shell" of my jquery that matches the SQL table and my web.config is setup correctly but my jquery doesnt load data. Where it says `url: 'ConnectionString',` I would like for it to point to my table or the web.config file. What can I do here. I need some guidance as this is something Im learning.

Thanks

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: 'Default.aspx',
            datatype: 'xml',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
  { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 55 },
  { name: 'Date', index: 'Date', width: 90 },
  { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: 'right' },
  { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: 'right' },
  { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: 'right' },
  { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: 'invid',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Joshs first grid'
        });
    }); 

</script>
```

My Aspx part as follows

```
<div class="ui-widget">

    <table id="list"></table> 

    <div id="pager"></div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how jQGrid works. It does not talk directly to your database at any point and it makes use of (optional) server-side libraries to format the response your server sends when the plugin requests data.

Please take a look at http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx for an example of using jQGrid with ASP.NET.